# Skip results inside a foreach loop - pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

In my database I store email addresses. In the foreach loop how can I skip all email addresses that has `@sample.com.ru`?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM myMovieCustomers";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach ($result as $row) {
    //skip if $row['email'] contains @sample.com.ru{
        //do someting with these
    //}
}
```

Comment: `strpos()` + `continue;`

Comment: you can add it in where clause of your query like .. `where email like '%@sample.com.ru'`

Comment: @kamalpal Thanks. But if add it after `WHERE` it will select them anyway. I need to skip rows that has `...@sample.com.ru`

Comment: oh missed that.. `email not like '%@sample.com.ru'` will work

Comment: @kamalpal That's cool. Just for the curiosity, what if I need to filter two email addresses instead of one?

Comment: simply add one more clause .. `and email not like '%@abc.com'`

Comment: @kamalpal Thanks. Can't it be done like `email NOT LIKE '%@sample1.com.ru' OR '%@sample2.com.ru'`

Comment: no that won't work .. that's something like .. `if($email != '%@sample.com.ru' or $email != '%@sample.com.ru') ..` it will get you all records.

Comment: @Becky Use `and`, `email NOT LIKE '%@sample1.com.ru' and  email '%@sample2.com.ru'`. or you could use a regex and allow for any number to follow the `sample`. Something like `email not regexp 'sample[0-9]+\.com.ru'`

Comment: What does the @ and % do in a SQL statement, and where can I read up on it?  (Not finding anything on google)

Comment: @SgtAJ the `%` is a [wildcard](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp) and the `@` is part of the address

Comment: Thanks!  I hadn't seen that before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's more efficient to do filtering at the database level for a couple of reasons

- you're not wasting network resources transmitting unneeded data across the wire
- with a well indexed table, the DBMS will be faster at making the search than php will with the result data

as is pointed out in the comments and other answers, you can use the [`LIKE`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) operator

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM myMovieCustomers WHERE email NOT LIKE '%@sample.com.ru'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want by using php function [strstr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)() like below:

```
$all = array(
            'name' => array('Thanga','Kima','Zara'),
            'email'=> array('thanga@gmail.com','kima@gmail.com','zara@sample.com.ru')
            );

echo '<pre>';
print_r($all);
foreach($all as $key=>$val):
    foreach ($val as $k=>$v):
        if(strstr($v,'@')=='@sample.com.ru'){
        }else{
            echo $v;
        }
    endforeach;
endforeach;
```

Comment: Why not put a `!=` in your **if** statement instead of a blank `==`?

Answer (score -1):

Just change the first line...

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM myMovieCustomers WHERE email NOT LIKE'%@sample.com.ru'";
```

Comment: you are missing ending single quote

Comment: @barry: single quote before last double quote is missing :) it should be like `'%@sample.com.ru'"`